# Grouping dummy table values using ID

Tags: r

I have a dummy table that gives a 1 if you have the product and 0 if you dont. This table was focused on product, so it has both client and product per line.

However, a client can have multiple products and appear in many lines. I want to group (by sum or count) all the products in one line. Example:

[image: Nulls are supposed to be zeros for the solution query to work]

Nulls are supposed to be zeros for the solution answer query to work

And I need this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(Client) %>% summarise_at(vars(TC:CA), function(x) sum(x))

 # Client    TC    CC    CA
#1 654        2     1     0
#2 666        0     0     1
#3 667        0     1     0
```

Data

```
df <- structure(list(Product = structure(c(3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("CA", 
"CC", "TC"), class = "factor"), Client = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("654", "666", "667"), class = "factor"), 
    TC = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0), CC = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1), CA = c(0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0)), .Names = c("Product", "Client", "TC", "CC", "CA"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It is returning the same value for all the variables: table%>%group_by(CODIGO_CLIENTE)%>%summarise_at(vars('Variable 3':'Variable 23'),function(x) sum(!is.na(x)))

Comment: @Invancito see my update. You if you have `0` rather than `NA`, take out the `!is.na`

Comment: Thank you. Even I had forgotten that the table was already turned into a dummy table (1,0)